# Need help figuring out which PDO database drivers contain an information_schema db (PHP)

Tags: php, pdo, information-schema

I am trying to make a generic extended PDO class. One of the methods pulls data from the db schema like so.

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ?
```

I am trying to figure out which of PDO's database drivers will this type of query not work with. I have read that information_schema is an ansi standard, but some database systems have not implimented it. I am only familiar with mysql, but need to make the class agile because other dbs may be used in the future.

Any info about which database systems use information_schema would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as a bonus, is there a workaround to get table column names for the rdbms that do not have information_schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out which of PDO's database drivers will this type of query not work with

This has nothing to do with PDO and everything to do with the underlying database engine.

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) and [MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) support `information_schema`.  Oracle and SQLite don't, meaning you'd need code specific to those database engines to query table information.

Comment: i mentioned pdo because i am only interested in information for rdbms that pdo can access. thanks.